# Text Field Troubleshooting in Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, uitextfield

As practice, I am trying to create a simple math app in which one can input two values as the bases of a right triangle and when they press a button the 3rd leg is calculated. This is the code I am using:

```
class pythagoreanTheoremViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var baseOneTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var baseTwoTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var answerLabel: UILabel!

    var a = baseOneTextField.text.toInt()
}
```

However, this returns the error that pythagoreanTheoremViewController.Type does not have a member named 'baseOneTextField'. I deleted and then reconnected my outlets and I still have the same problem.

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `var a` declaration is positioned at the top level of your `class`, so it is an instance variable. But an instance variable's initialization cannot refer to another instance variable (`baseOneTextField`), because the object is not yet formed at initialization time - forming the object is exactly what we are in the middle of doing.

Comment: I tried the lazy var workaround you posted in response to the other question but I still have the same error.

Comment: Actually it's a different error. _Two_ different errors. You need to say `self.baseOneTextField.text!.toInt()` - notice the `self` and the exclamation mark.

Comment: I must admit that I do not see why an obvious duplicate must be answered at all. There seem to be different opinions on meta, but as I understand http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286283/should-users-be-permitted-to-both-answer-and-close-a-question, answering and then immediately dupe-hammer-closing is frowned upon.

Comment: @MartinR I agree, actually.